# Regular expression to extract incremental number within strings

Tags: regex

I am using muti-file rename tool that can rename filenames based ona regular expression pattern. For instance I have filenames like these:

```
Otrazenie.(01.serija.iz.12).2011.XviD.SATRip.RiperAM.avi
Otrazenie.(02.serija.iz.12).2011.XviD.SATRip.RiperAM.avi
Otrazenie.(03.serija.iz.12).2011.XviD.SATRip.RiperAM.avi
```

Or like these:

```
Beauty.and.the.Beast.S01E01.LostFilm.TV.avi
Beauty.and.the.Beast.S01E02.LostFilm.TV.avi
Beauty.and.the.Beast.S01E03.LostFilm.TV.avi
```

Here we have only number inside the string that changes (01,02,03...)

How to build a RegEx to get just that number from a string?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You were great in Alien and Ghostbusters.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score -1):

It's not always possible to predict the value in a series that will change based on a single file.  For example, imagine pulling episode numbers from season 2 of the 24 tv series.  There are three possible series values in the file name `24_02_07.avi`.  It's not clear which number is the series value until the next file name (`24_02_08.avi`) is revealed.

Taking this into consideration, you can run the following bash script.  It first finds the longest common prefix among the files of the current directory.  It then finds the number in each file name that follows the prefix:

```
set -- *
files=$#

prefix=$1
while [ -n "$prefix" ]; do
  set -- $prefix*
  [ $# -eq $files ] && break
  prefix=${prefix%?}
done

ls | sed -e "s/$prefix\([0-9]*\).*/\1/g" | sort -nu
```

I'm assuming that since there was no language mentioned, we're on the command line.

The prefix is found using [Chris F.A. Johnson](http://cfajohnson.com/)'s solution to [finding the longest common substring among filenames](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/93124-finding-longest-common-substring-among-filenames.html).